# How to config IPN for PayPal Express Checkout?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I would like use PayPal Express Checkout and I use the official client side example of PayPal.

https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

```
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>

    // Render the PayPal button

    paypal.Button.render({
x
        // Set your environment

        env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

        // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
        // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create

        client: {
            sandbox:    'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
            production: '<insert production client id>'
        },

        // Set to 'Pay Now'

        commit: true,

        // Wait for the PayPal button to be clicked

        payment: function(actions) {

            // Make a client-side call to the REST api to create the payment

            return actions.payment.create({
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

            // Execute the payment

            return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                window.alert('Payment Complete!');
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button-container');

</script>
```

My question is, how I can pass the notifiy_url to get the confirmation of payment and the data of the customer?

I assuming that onAuthorize function isn't enough.
If someone could clarify I will appreciate.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the REST APIs you need to use [Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/), not IPN.  IPN is for the Classic APIs.

Comment: Do express checkouts not trigger IPNs?

Comment: Express Checkout on Classic API would trigger IPNs.  Express Checkout on REST API would trigger webhooks.

Comment: So the Express checkout using the javascript implementation doesn't trigger IPNs?

Comment: Found out I can create a sandbox merchant account with IPNs configured. I can confirm, IPNs still happen with the JS express checkout. Webhooks are optional (phew).